# Does editing asp.net razor chtml file require recompiling?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I wanted to 'live' edit Razor view files *.chtml files in my production MVC website and was wondering if It requires me to recompile my webapp or will it cause the IIS Apppool to restart. I tried on my local machine and it seems that I can edit without need to recompile but needed definitive answer or documentation confirming this.

I also tried this with *.aspx files in webforms, it seems i can edit the aspx file without the need of recompiling as long as the *.designer file does not change, that is I don't add/remove any runat=server controls on the aspx file, I can only edit plain HTML markup.

Comment: By default, it doesn't require compiling *by you*, but there is still compilation that will happen by ASP.NET - see [ASP.NET Compilation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723(v=vs.100).aspx), which describe the entire "behind-the-scenes" process.  From a Visual Studio perspective, [ASP.NET Web Application Project Precompilation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464.aspx) has some good information, too.

Answer (score 7):

No, it does not require compiling. There is, however, an option when building the app to compile the views.

Comment: Correct on both accounts, but the view compilation is typically only used to ensure you don't have any bad syntax/references to non-existent model properties and does not impact your .dlls generated by the compiler.  Typically, most only compile views in 'Debug' mode since that is your test build.  Production compilations can have this turned off to increase build speed.

Comment: so where is the option?